# Setting font weight bold without importing bold from google fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-size, google-font-api

I am using google fonts on my web applications. I imported the regular weight of the font **Kumbh Sans** and used it in `<h1>` tag of my web app. When I view my app from google chrome and firefox, I noticed that my `<h1>` texts looks thinner in firefox.

Then I imported both regular and bold weight of that font and now it looks the same in both browsers, but it looks thicker than the previous version in chrome, which I liked more.

My question is, how browsers render bold fonts when I import only regular weight fonts? Why it looks different in chrome and firefox? And should I use the bold font without importing the bold version from google font?